# Can I limit download/upload speeds in JSF/PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, download, limit

I am using JSF with PrimeFaces and the upload/download components fit my project perfectly. However, since the software will be deployed in some low-bandwidth environments, I was just wondering whether it is possible to limit the upload/download speeds these components will use?

Thanks for your suggestions and best regards
Pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no out-of-the-box approach. I ended up writing an own "LimitedInputStream" implementation.

LimitedInputStream:

```
public class LimitedInputStream extends InputStream {
    public static InputStream create(ILimitedInputStreamPolicy policy, InputStream wrapped) {
        return new LimitedInputStream(policy, wrapped);
    }

    public static InputStream create(Logger log, InputStream wrapped) {
        final ILimitedInputStreamPolicy policy = BytesPerIntervalLimitedInputStreamPolicy.create(log);
        return new LimitedInputStream(policy, wrapped);
    }

    private final ILimitedInputStreamPolicy policy;
    private final InputStream wrapped;

    private LimitedInputStream(ILimitedInputStreamPolicy policy, InputStream wrapped) {
        this.policy = policy;
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public int available() throws IOException {
        return wrapped.available();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        wrapped.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return wrapped.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return wrapped.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void mark(int readlimit) {
        wrapped.mark(readlimit);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean markSupported() {
        return wrapped.markSupported();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        policy.waitForBytesToRead();
        final int result = wrapped.read();
        policy.bytesRead(1);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        final long bytesLeft = policy.waitForBytesToRead();
        final int bytesToRead = Long.valueOf(Math.min(bytesLeft, len)).intValue();
        final int bytesRead = wrapped.read(b, off, bytesToRead);
        policy.bytesRead(bytesRead);
        return bytesRead;
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() throws IOException {
        wrapped.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        return wrapped.skip(n);
    }
}
```

ILimitedInputStreamPolicy.java:

```
/**
 * Implementing class provide information about in which intervals how much data
 * may be read from a stream.
 */
public interface ILimitedInputStreamPolicy {
    /**
     * Indicates that the given number of bytes have been read in any atomic
     * action.
     * 
     * @param numberOfBytes
     *            The number of bytes read.
     */
    public void bytesRead(int numberOfBytes);

    /**
     * Pauses the current thread until the implemented policy allows for the
     * returned amount of bytes to read,
     * 
     * @return The number of bytes allowed to read.
     */
    public int waitForBytesToRead();
}
```